# Qiwi curl авторизация

Tags: php, curl, qiwi

Есть скрипт, сегодня проверил, после авторизации выдаёт 301 Moved Permanently, может кто знает решение.

```
<?php
$U_LOGIN = "+7**********";
$U_PASS = "";
$cookie_file = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
$arr = array("login" => $U_LOGIN,"password" => $U_PASS);
$post = json_encode($arr);
$url="https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/tgts?".$post;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/vnd.qiwi.sso-v1+json','Accept-Language: ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4','Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate','X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://visa.qiwi.com/main.action');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$page = json_decode($html, true);
$arr = array("ticket" => $page['entity']['ticket'],"service" => "https://visa.qiwi.com/j_spring_cas_security_check");
$post = json_encode($arr);

$url="https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/sts?".$post;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/vnd.qiwi.sso-v1+json','Accept-Language: ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4','Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate','X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://auth.qiwi.com/app/proxy?v=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$arr = array("service" => "https://visa.qiwi.com/j_spring_cas_security_check","ticket" => $page['entity']['ticket']);
$post = json_encode($arr);

$url="https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/sts?".$post;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/vnd.qiwi.sso-v1+json','Accept-Language: ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4','Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate','X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://visa.qiwi.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$page = json_decode($html, true);
$url="https://visa.qiwi.com/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=".$page["entity"]["ticket"];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://visa.qiwi.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

$url="https://visa.qiwi.com/report/list.action?type=3";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://visa.qiwi.com/main.action');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Куда переадресует этот редирект?

Answer (score -3):

```html
<?php
$U_LOGIN = "+***";
$U_PASS = "***";
$cookie_file = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
$arr = array("login" => $U_LOGIN,"password" => $U_PASS);
$post = json_encode($arr);
$url="https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/tgts?".$post;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/vnd.qiwi.sso-v1+json','Accept-Language: ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4','Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate','X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://qiwi.com/main.action');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$page = json_decode($html, true);
$arr = array("ticket" => $page['entity']['ticket'],"service" => "https://qiwi.com/j_spring_cas_security_check");
$post = json_encode($arr);

$url="https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/sts?".$post;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/vnd.qiwi.sso-v1+json','Accept-Language: ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4','Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate','X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://auth.qiwi.com/app/proxy?v=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$arr = array("service" => "https://qiwi.com/j_spring_cas_security_check","ticket" => $page['entity']['ticket']);
$post = json_encode($arr);

$url="https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/sts?".$post;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/vnd.qiwi.sso-v1+json','Accept-Language: ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4','Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate','X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://qiwi.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$page = json_decode($html, true);
$url="https://qiwi.com/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=".$page["entity"]["ticket"];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://qiwi.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

$url="https://qiwi.com/report/list.action?type=3";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://qiwi.com/main.action');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: и он рабочий? вы только visa. потёрли

Comment: Да рабочий, не скидывал если бы не работал.